# HTTPclient inputstream crashes android app

Tags: android, httpclient

My app works just fine before I add this code, I tried a separate android project with this code and it works just fine...

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/jan/android/fave.php");
        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray the_json_array = object.getJSONArray("products");

            int length = the_json_array.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
              {
                JSONObject another_json_object = the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);
            String verion = another_json_object.optString("title");
              }
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This one is for the inputstream

```
  private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String rLine = "";
    StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    try {
     while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      answer.append(rLine);
       }
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return answer;
   }
```

But when I add it to this code, the app crashes, I have been debugging this for more than 12 hours now and I am nowhere close to fixing it.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/jan/android/fave.php");
        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String jsonResult =    inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray the_json_array = object.getJSONArray("products");

            int length = the_json_array.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
              {
                JSONObject another_json_object = the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);
            String verion = another_json_object.optString("title");
              }
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



     // Create an instance of editorFrag
        mainFragment firstFrag = new mainFragment();

        // add fragment to the fragment container layout
        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, firstFrag);
        ft.commit(); 

    // 1. pass context and data to the custom adapter
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());

    // if extending Activity 2. Get ListView from activity_main.xml
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    // 3. setListAdapter
    //listView.setAdapter(adapter); if extending Activity
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

 // App Icon 
drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this,                  /* host Activity */
        drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
        R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
        R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
        );

// Set actionBarDrawerToggle as the DrawerListener
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 

// just styling option add shadow the right edge of the drawer
drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

}

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
         actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

 // call ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(), if it returns true
// then it has handled the app icon touch event
if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private ArrayList<Model> generateData(){
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/janime/android/fave.php");
    ArrayList<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>();
    models.add(new Model("SmileyChix", "http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2013/001/3/8/ouma_shu___guilty_crown_wallpaper_lost_christmas_by_akije_hirodi-d5q45lh.jpg"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_action_dock,"Latest",null));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_action_storage,"Watchlist","12"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_action_settings,"Settings",null));


    try
    {



        String the_json = "{'products':[{'title':'test'},{'title':'test'}],'success':1}";
        JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(the_json);
        JSONArray the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("products");
        int length = the_json_array.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
        JSONObject another_json_object = the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);
        String artist_name = another_json_object.optString("title").toString();
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_drawer, artist_name,"12"));
      }

    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return models;
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.passId);
        String tEXT = text.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     // Create an instance of editorFrag
        videoList firstFrag = new videoList();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("key", tEXT);
        firstFrag.setArguments(bundle);
        // add fragment to the fragment container layout
        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, firstFrag);

        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit(); 
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

        }



}       

private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String rLine = "";
    StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    try {
     while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      answer.append(rLine);
       }
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return answer;
   }

}
```

Logcat

```
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.janime/android.janime.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1144)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at android.janime.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:91)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
    11-07 21:50:49.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30662):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Without the stacktrace I doubt anyone will be able to help so please add that aswell...

Comment: sorry about that... I added it now

Comment: Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

that's your problem. you can not run network requests on the main thread. you nead to use something like AsyncTask or some other way of threading.

Comment: [read this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) it should get you started on the right path

Comment: thank you very much, I will try to study that :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not launch a HttpRequest in the **onCreate** method, 
but most important is that you should launch it in other thread.

Depending on the version of Android target http requests in main thread are not allowed.

Post stacktrace, please

Comment: Im new to java/android, if I understand it correctly, the stacktrace is in the logcat? where could I get the stacktrace?

Comment: you already pasted the stacktrace and even got the answer. The http request need to run on a separate thread. The main thread mostly takes care of UI changes. if you would be allowed to make network calls on main thread the whole app would freeze while waiting for response from the server.

Comment: Yes, the stacktrace is showed in logcat. I'm afraid i didn't refresh the page after you post the trace xD.